# Why is my JSESSIONID now called just SESSION?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I have noticed something unusual. Instead usual JSESSIONID for Spring boot 1.3.5/spring security/Embedded tomcat 8

`JSESSIONID 7B1ADB8E38C5E1CEBD81C4AD88FEEC30 domain.com 42 B/ Session HttpOnly`

I am now getting :

`SESSION    fd0ef173-e17a-440e-8d76-bc63025b3273 domain.com 43 B/ Session HttpOnly`

Also token looks more lika UUID now. I have tested it, it works but i was just curious why is this happening?

This started happening recently even when i create entirely new project with form login. 
Maybe i have missed something in spring documentation about it?

Comment: Are you by chance using spring-session? http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/

Comment: No spring-session.